What is the h-level of "un-truncated" real numbers in HoTT?
In the HoTT book, (11.3.3) $\mathbb{R}_c$ (the Cauchy Reals) are defined using a type family ~ satisfying properties 1-4 and

for any u, v, ϵ, if $ξ, ζ : u ∼_ϵ v$, then $ξ = ζ$ (propositional truncation)

This final property is essential to proving that $\mathbb{R}_c$ is an h-set, suggesting that the real numbers without this truncation are at least a 1-groupoid.
There are other, and not necessarily constructively equivalent, definitions of $\mathbb{R}$, but all of them seem to pull in some number of propositional truncations in order to ensure that it remains a set.
If we were to drop this part of the definition, and allow the reals to not be a set, what kind of structure(s) can we end up with? What would their h-level(s) be? And what would be the main downsides to allowing pairs of real numbers to equal each other in nonequal ways?
